# Change Position of svg element using JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Trying to make an svg rectangle that moves when button pushed. Right now I just want the x to be modified by a function.

```js
function modX()
{
  document.getElementById("rectangle").transform = 'translate(295 115)';
}
var x = 20;
var y = 20;
modX();
```

```html
<svg  width="1000" height="1000" >
  <rect id="rectangle" x="0" y="20" width="100" height="100" 
  style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect>
</svg>
```

I'm fairly new to code so please avoid css or jquery.

Comment: style.transform

Comment: btw you're using css transform translate is css and the style you're applying to the rect is css :)

Answer (score 10):

you can change its x by using javaScript `document.getElementById("rectangle").setAttribute('x', X_value)`
set the `X_value` to the value you want it to change.